# set databinding of combobox to a property int of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I need bind a comboBox ValueMember to a property int of an Object.

```
private void setBinds()
{
    comboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Employee, "FiscalDocType", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Employee:

```
public class Employee
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int FiscalDocType { get; set; }
     public string FiscalDoc {  get; set; }
}
```

Set of DataSource:

```
 comboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
 comboBox.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
 comboBox.DataSource = listOfCombo //Type: List<ComboModel>;
```

ComboModel:

```
public class ComboModel
{
    public int ValueMember { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMember { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DisplayMember;
    }
}
```

When the value of the combo changes do not save the ValueMember to bind property. Also the comboBox does not lose the focus.

If I try convert the SelectedValue to int , it returns a conversion error types.

```
int integer = (int)SelectedValue;
int integer2 = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedValue);
int integer3 = int.Parse(SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Any option is valid.

Can help me?

Comment: `DisplayMember ` and `ValueMember` should be set to the *property name* in the class  for example `"FiscalDoc"` and `"Id"`

Comment: The code looks ok. Please provide [mcve].